# Calling Flash functions from C# and vice versa

Tags: c#, flash

What's the proper way to communicate with Flash from C# when it's hosted in the ActiveX control?  I see a CallFunction method which look promising to communicate with Flash but I'm having a hard time finding documentation about what the parameter data should look like.  Also, what would the reverse look like; i.e. how could the Flash content notify C# of some kind of event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use SetVariable and CallFunction to achieve this.  Here is a [good, short tutorial on Flash and C# interop](http://bojordan.com/log/?p=269).